# unique url to each username in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a website in which i want to create a unique url for each user account.

means

```
http://example.com/username => route to controler/index/username

http://example.com/username2 => route to controler/index/username2
```

i am using codeigniter and the pattern of URL is :

```
http://exaple.com/controller name/method name/argument
```

I am getting no idea that how can we do this kind of routing just like facebook do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CI routing you can achieve this very easily.

In your `routes.php` config (application/config/route.php) file you add a line similar to this one:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/index/$1";
```

The left bit is the one you type or have in your browsers address bar. The right bit is what it routes to. In your case the name of the controller and method, followed by the argument. For your case that will be the user. It's an alphanumeric variable so that's how you pass it.

The complete reference can be found here, but the example above should make everything clear:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: and it is not fullfilling my purpose ....... it redirects to the routed controller whenever i am trying to execute any string (even the name of controller )

Comment: ```$1``` is a variable, in this the first of that uri, hence the number 1

It's the one that passes the ```username```  argument to your method

Comment: It is doing exactly what it should do. If you don't want any given string to route to it you'll have to add that to your function. eg if(is_username($var)) etc... It's a different question though

Comment: and if we write    $route['(:any)'] it will treat everything as "any string" and redirect to the controller that i made

Comment: i mean to say that the controllers method i am calling earlier are not calling....... only index method and the controller are running, nothing else is working

Comment: Did you find what was happening? If not maybe you can update your question with a part of your controller. It seems you have accepted the answer so I'm guessing you did!

Answer (score 0):

The argument `http://exaple.com/controller_name/method_name/argument` section is what needs to be unique in your case.

Comment: no, i don't want name of controller and method to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy with codeigniter routes. Have a look at the manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You need modify the .htacces to replace index.php for example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /<your_root_foler>/%{HTTP_HOST}
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /<your_root_foler>/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

This line (RewriteRule ^(.*)$ //%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1 [L]) replace all index.php in your app where do you use codeigniter

Afte you can modify your  routes.php like say "bottleboot"

Comment: thats a differnt thing , it is not my concern ......... i juss wanna say that if i am not writing anything in url then it is redirecting to default controller and if i write anything(even the name of another controller) then it shows problem